# After creating a <text> element with javascript, why can't I getBBox?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

I have a script that adds a `<text>` element to my markup, inside an existing `<svg>`. Running `getBBox()` on that new element gives me an error. If I include the `<text>` in the markup to begin with and run an equivalent script, getBBox runs without any problems. Is the DOM not fully treating my js-built `<text>` as a text element… am I missing some "the thing written '<text>' is in fact a `<text>`" step?

```js
function works() {
  console.log('start "works"')
  var svgElem = document.querySelector('.works');
  var textElem = svgElem.querySelector('text');
  var textBBox = textElem.getBBox();
  console.log(textBBox);
  console.log('end "works"')
}
works();

function doesntwork() {
  console.log('start "doesntwork"')
  var svgElem = document.querySelector('.doesntwork');
  var textElem = document.createElement("text");
  textElem.appendChild(svgElem.firstChild);
  svgElem.appendChild(textElem);
  console.log('"doesntwork" breaks after this');
  var textBBox = textElem.getBBox(); // breaks the script
  console.log(textBBox);
  console.log('end "doesntwork"')
}
doesntwork();
```

```html
<svg class="doesntwork">
  not working
</svg>

<svg class="works">
  <text>
    working
  </text>
</svg>
```

---

**Less generic second part:**

In my full project, I'm actually turning

```
<div class="target">content</div>
```

into

```
<div class="target"><svg><text>content</text></svg></div>
```

using js to create a `<text>` and an `<svg>`. The idea is basically

```
var targetElems = document.querySelectorAll('.target');
for (var i = 0; i < targetElems.length; ++i) { // for each target
    var targetElem = targetElems[i];
    var textElem = document.createElement("text"); // build a <text>
    while (targetElem.firstChild) // put the target's content (which could include child elements) in the <text>
        textElem.appendChild(targetElem.firstChild);
    var svgElem = document.createElement("svg"); // build an <svg>
    svgElem.appendChild(textElem); // put the <text> in the <svg> 
    targetElem.appendChild(svgElem); // put the <svg> in the target
    var textBBox = textElem.getBBox(); // want to be able to get the <text>'s BBox (this currently has a breaking error)
    console.log(textBBox);
}
```

Do I have to add a signal at *each* step - "this is a `<text>`, this is an `<svg>`"?

Or am I going about the whole thing wrong / is there some smarter way to turn `.target > [content]` into `.target > svg > text > [content]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use: [createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS).

> `document.createElementNS(String namespaceURI, String qualifiedName)`.
>
> Where:
>
> ```
> namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
> name = "text"
> ```

Something like this:

```js
function worksnow() {
  console.log('start "worksnow"')
  var svgElem = document.querySelector('.worksnow');
  var textElem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text"); // CHANGED THIS
  textElem.appendChild(svgElem.firstChild);
  svgElem.appendChild(textElem);
  var textBBox = textElem.getBBox(); // no longer breaks the script!
  console.info(textBBox); // Gets SVGRect data.
  console.log('end "worksnow"')
}
worksnow();
```

```html
<svg class="worksnow">
  works now!
</svg>
```

So, in the console, you'll get this:

[image: SVG]

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I need. Thanks! Fwiw, in case any future person wonders, my full example works when I use `createElementNS` for both the `<text>` and `<svg>`

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, if you need create **any** `svg` tag, use: `createElementNS `, always. Thanks for the edit.